# How can I set up a table inside a list in ScrewTurn Wiki?

Tags: list, screwturn

I need to have a table inside of a numbered list in ScrewTurn Wiki.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be much (any) documentation out there on how to do something like that.

Here is example markup:

```
# list item 1
# list item with table
{| 
|- 
! Column1 !! Column2
|- 
| Stuff1 || Stuff2
|}
# list item 4
```

If I look at that in the Wiki it generates the list numbers correctly, but instead of a table I see just the markup.

Any idea how to get that to render to a table?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding blank lines above and below the table markup.  eg.

```
# list item 1
# list item with table

{| 
|- 
! Column1 !! Column2
|- 
| Stuff1 || Stuff2
|}

# list item 4
```

Comment: It works for me.  What version of STW are you using?